# Monitoring Outline VPN: How to Access Performance Metrics of an Outline Server?

Tags: prometheus, vpn

I'm using the [Outline VPN](https://getoutline.org) server and I'm interested in accessing detailed performance metrics like:

- Concurrent connections
- Bytes used
- CPU and memory consumption

While the [outline-ss-server repository](https://github.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-ss-server) on GitHub refers to Prometheus metrics for whitebox monitoring, it doesn't explain how to retrieve or view these metrics.

Additionally, the Outline Manager interface seems to be limited, providing only the last 28 days of usage data for each access key.

How can I get more comprehensive metrics for monitoring and debugging purposes?

---

*Disclosure: I'm the engineering lead for the Outline VPN, and this is a frequent question I get. I would like to document the answer as public knowledge, as [encouraged by Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).*

Comment: You forgot to add disclosure of your relation to mentioned service. Until it's added this post can be treated as spam.

Comment: @markalex thanks for the heads up. I've added a disclosure.

Answer (score 2):

## Instructions

1. Connect to your server and forward port 9090:

```bash
ssh root@${SERVER} -L 9090:localhost:9090
```

2. Open https://localhost:9090/graph on your browser
3. Write the [PromQL](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/) query you need. See examples below.

## Example Queries

### Usage

#### Data Bytes

By access key, protocol and direction

```
increase(shadowsocks_data_bytes[1d])
```

To aggregate by access key only:

```
sum(increase(shadowsocks_data_bytes[1d])) by (access_key)
```

This is the query used to calculate the usage for data limits (from [manager_metrics.ts](https://github.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-server/blob/1ac9f238132d5917b42d4b6615727e477aa7bbc0/src/shadowbox/server/manager_metrics.ts#L31)):

```
sum(increase(shadowsocks_data_bytes{dir=~"c<p|p>t"}[30d])) by (access_key)
```

By location, protocol and direction

```
increase(shadowsocks_data_bytes_per_location[1d])
```

#### Active Access Keys

```
sum(max(max_over_time(shadowsocks_data_bytes{access_key!=""} [1h])) by (access_key) > bool 0)
```

#### TCP connections

By access key, location and status

```
increase(shadowsocks_tcp_connections_closed[1d])
```

By location

```
increase(shadowsocks_tcp_connections_opened[1d])
```

#### UDP

Packets by location and status

```
increase(shadowsocks_udp_packets_from_client_per_location[1d])
```

Associations (no breakdown)

```
increase(shadowsocks_udp_nat_entries_added[1d])
```

### Performance

CPU usage by process

```
rate(process_cpu_seconds_total[10m])
```

Memory by process

```
process_virtual_memory_bytes
```

### Build Info

Prometheus

```
prometheus_build_info
```

outline-ss-server

```
shadowsocks_build_info
```

Node.js

```
nodejs_version_info
```

## Reference

The full list of metrics provided by `outline-ss-server` can be found in [its source code](https://github.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-ss-server/blob/master/cmd/outline-ss-server/metrics.go).